# Background-Color & Animation don't work /display on the button

Tags: html, sass

Please see my codepen link below with the code!!! I am using scss

````
```https://codepen.io/reewebza/pen/gORmJJz```
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not only link us to another webpage to show us your code. You should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here in the question instead, because it will be hard for us dig through the whole code to find the problem. Goodluck :D

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`btn--white` is class, not pseudo-class

The way you need to declare styles for class is
`.btn--white { background-color: white; }`

Comment: Thank you...Something strange is happening...I am using the live sass compiler of Glenn Marks..When I change one of the sass files the "main.scss" files is amending itself/changing itself  which is why I have this problem